# Git local submodules inside single remote

Tags: android, git, flutter, git-submodules, git-subtree

How to make a repository with 3 subfolders with its own commits history and push them together to a single remote?

Android, iOS - repositories for native apps that can be checked and had their own histories.

Flutter - flutter repo that has Android and iOS folders as submodules plus some Flutter files.

Don't want to blend together commits and branches for all platforms.

For now, I can't even get a single Android repository inside it's own folder. **Submodules and subtrees work fine locally. But subfolders can't be pushed to the single remote together since these submodules don't have actual remote URL - they are just local subfolders**.

Different repos can't be used- all three platforms have to be inside one repo.

---

[image: Structure]

Answer (score 0):

git is not intended to work that way.  One URL = one repo = one commit chain.

If you ever want to break it up, you can use `git subtree` (last found in the contrib dir when I looked).